# How to do a JavaScript action when Laravel Dropdown menu selected special item

Tags: php, laravel

Here is a part of Laravel drop-down menu.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group mb-20">
        <label><strong>{{trans('string.select_wallet')}}</strong></label>
        {!!Form::select('Wallet_id', $WalletList, null,
                         ['class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required'])!!}
    </div>
</div>
```

In this WalletList, 2 wallet A & B are able to be selected.
I would like to have a JavaScript when B wallet is selected, how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

First provide an Id to `Select` to identify `Select` or change `Event`:

```
{!!Form::select('Wallet_id', $WalletList, null,
        ['class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required', 'id' => 'Wallet_id'])!!}
```

After that use jQuery for fetching event and executing code:

```
$('#Wallet_id').change(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == 'B'){
        /* Do Something */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the element

```
{!!Form::select('Wallet_id', $WalletList, null,['class'=>'form-
control','required'=>'required', 'id' => 'MySelect'])!!}
```

and use jQuery:

```
var element = document.getElementById("MySelect");
var selectedElement = element.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

and just search with JavaScript when the item changes:

```
if (selectedElement == (text of your B element))
{
  //do what you want to do.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and made me learned more =)